# Putting a table inside a hyperlink - not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, hyperlink, html-table

I have a table inside a hyperlink:

```
<a href="/"><table><tr><td>...</td></tr></table></a>
```

In all browsers, hovering over the table changes the pointer to a hand, and through some CSS the table background changes colour (so it looks 'highlighted').

However, in Internet Explorer, clicking the table has no effect. In Firefox and Chrome, it follows the hyperlink as expected.

How can I make IE follow the link when clicked?

Comment: Have you tried a javascript onclick event for the table? Like: onclick="javascript:window.location='/';" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't nest block-level elements inside of inline elements and expect to get proper results (*insert citation here*).

You could add some CSS styles to the table and apply a `onclick` handler so that it acts like a hyperlink:

```
<table style="fakeLink" onclick="window.location = '/';">...
```

And the `fakeLink` class:

```
.fakeLink
{
  color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline; /* Not sure if this is possible. */
}
```

*And* a demo demonstrating the two techniques: http://jsfiddle.net/qNGrp/4/. I don't have IE, but I think only one will work properly.

Comment: You can wrap links around block-level elements in HTML5, though I think you need a polyfill for backwards compatibility with IE.

Comment: HTML5 is arguably easier than HTML4 - checkout HTML5 Boilerplate for a jumpstart.

Comment: I first saw HTML5 here: http://flask.pocoo.org/. I was like "**HOW DOES THIS THING VALIDATE?!?!??!**" There was no `<head>`, no `<body>`, no closing tags for the `<li>`s. It was quite disturbing...

Comment: Yeah - some people are going a bit overboard, using HTML5 syntax for the sake of it, even though it frequently makes it more confusing. However, in the sense of just using HTML4 with a few extra elements, and a bit more flexibility for existing elements, it's great. Links around block elements are a good example. Putting `<nav>` and `<aside>` and the like are great too, because you apply CSS to them and still have specificity with CSS ID selectors.

Comment: Oh yes, the new tag selection is great. I'll have to break my constant `<div>` nesting habits soon!

Comment: I especially like `<header>` and `<footer>`, and `<nav>`. They'll make Wordpress a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 3):

First: Putting an `<a>` around block-level elements IS valid in HTML5! Check the code below on http://validator.w3.org/

Second: Any JavaScript work-around reduces accessibility, so it's not the best thing to do ;-)

My solution: Use `<div>`'s instead of `<table>` - as shown here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MSIE sucks!</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:alert('Yeah!')">
<table>
<tr>
<td>&lt;table&gt; Doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8 :-(</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div style="display:table">
<div style="display:table-row">
<div style="display:table-cell">Solution: &lt;div style=&quot;display:table&quot;&gt;</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find a solution for this, it's not perfect but it works:

### Simplified CSS:

```
a{ display:inline-block; position:relative; }
a:after{ content:''; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:url('x'); }
```

### Simplified HTML:

```
<a href='http://dropthebit.com' target='_blank'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
        <td>cell 3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</a>
```

[**Test page**](http://jsfiddle.net/hekW9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't work.  IE has the correct behaviour there.  Tables are block-level elements; links are inline elements.  Inline elements may not contain block-level elements.

If you want clicking on your element to change the page, you will probably need Javascript.  Changing the CSS shouldn't be difficult, though: the `:hover` pseudo-selector will still work on the `table` element.

Comment: logically this is a flawed internet behavior. obviously for almost ~18 years the internet exists, people would need to wrap a whole table in a link. it makes sense, and it's a very flawed design you cannot do that in IE.